# do we use blocking or non-blocking statement while we make latch in verilog?

Tags: verilog, digital

what is right way to make latch in verilog?
When i try synthesizing both ways on vivado i get latch generated in both the cases.i am trying to understand do we use blocking statement or non-blocking statement?

i) always @(enable,input)
begin
q <= input;
end

ii) always @(enable,input)
begin
q = input;
end

Answer (score 1):

Use blocking assignments.

For synthesis, only use non-blocking assignments for edge sensitive sequential logic.

Comment: Seems that Cummings in "Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!" recommends nonblocking for latches. Do you have a reason for suggesting using blocking assignments instead?

Comment: @cic Unless you need to provide non-blocking delays, like `q<= #1 in;` non-blocking assignments have no benefit for latches.

Answer (score 1):

None of the ways you provided should be used to make latches.

Commonly used programming pattern looks like the following:

```
always @*
   if (en)
       q <= inp;
```